# namespace aliasing in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone advise me on below Javascript -

1) How can I use the "Base" variable?

2) In callShowMsg function, a local variable "ns" is used to alias the namespace.

Is it possible to use a global variable to alias the namespace? It will avoid the need to declare local variable in each function.

Thanks in advance.

My code is,

```
var Base = namespace("MyCo.MyApp.Myprogram");

MyCo.MyApp.Myprogram = 
    {

        showMsg: function (pMsg) 
        {
            alert(pMsg);
        },

        callShowMsg: function (pMsg) 
        {

            var ns = MyCo.MyApp.Myprogram;            
            ns.showMsg('Hello');            

        }

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid JavaScript to me.

Comment: @thefourtheye Looks totally valid to me. `namespace` is presumably just a function for defining a nested object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this: (YUI with some fallback for custom namespace). Though I believe you do not have to "namespace" or reference the obj. Just refer to it as "this".
So, if you are within the obj, you can call the methods like so: this.showMsg('somevalue')

```
function createNamespace() {
var uniqueNS = "MyCo";
var a = arguments, o, i = 0, j, d, arg,
    ns = this,
    PERIOD = ".";

// force namespace to MyCo
ns.uniqueNS = ns.uniqueNS || {};
ns = ns.uniqueNS;

for (; i < a.length; i++) {
  o = ns; //Reset base object per argument or it will get reused from the last
  arg = a[i];
  if (arg.indexOf(PERIOD) > -1) { //Skip this if no "." is present
    d = arg.split(PERIOD);
    for (j = (d[0] == uniqueNS) ? 1 : 0; j < d.length; j++) {
      o[d[j]] = o[d[j]] || {};
      o = o[d[j]];
    }
  } else {
    o[arg] = o[arg] || {};
    o = o[arg]; //Reset base object to the new object so it's returned
  }
}
   return o;
 }

var Base = createNamespace("MyCo.MyApp.Myprogram");

Base = 
   {

      showMsg: function (pMsg) 
       {
           alert(pMsg);
       },

       callShowMsg: function (pMsg) 
       {        
        this.showMsg(pMsg);            

        }

   }

  Base.showMsg('ok');
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is some function like namespace like you wrote above,
You can do something like that:

```
var MYAPPLICATION = {
    calculateVat: function (base) {
        return base * 1.21;
    },
    product: function (price) {
        this.price = price;
        this.getPrice = function(){
                          return this.price;
                       };
    },
    doCalculations: function () {
        var p = new MYAPPLICATION.product(100);
        alert(this.calculateVat(p.getPrice()));
    }
}
```

Or If you want to use nested namespaces you can try this:

```
var MYAPPLICATION = {
    MODEL: {
        product: function (price) { 
                     this.price = price; 
                    this.getPrice = function(){
                         return this.price;
                     };
                 }
    },
    LOGIC: {
        calculateVat: function (base) {
            return base * 1.21;
        },
        doCalculations: function () {
            var p = new MYAPPLICATION.MODEL.product(100);
            alert(this.calculateVat(p.getPrice()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. How can I use the "Base" variable?

   That is going to depend on what value got returned by the `namespace` function. This is not a standard JS function and its probably specific to the libraries you are using so I cant answer.
2. Is it possible to use a global variable to alias the namespace?

Of course.

```
var ns = {
    callShowMsg: function (pMsg) 
    {         
        ns.showMsg('Hello');            
    }
}

MyCo.MyApp.Myprogram = ns;
```

You can also make ns into a local function instead of a global by putting it inside an initialization functions intead of putting it on the script toplevel. The most common way of doing that is using an immediately invoked anonymous function:

```
(function(){
   var ns = {
        callShowMsg: function (pMsg) 
        {         
            ns.showMsg('Hello');            
        }
    }

    MyCo.MyApp.Myprogram = ns;
}());
```